# Nested Nested column in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, lambda, nested

Have a nested nested column in a pandas dataframe, which I received after json_normalize the request, looking like this:

```
  {  
   'Speed':352,
   'type':[  
      {  
         'details':'change\n',
         'id':'3129f48c-23a6-49bd-9854',
         'machine':'logs',
         'Cause':{  
            'code':'051',
            'description':'Error',
            'id':'41827d41-75c5-4c88-9ec3',
            'reason':'Error'
         }
      }
   ],
   'endTime':1522844263021,
   'line':'73c2f337-46fc-415c-a24f',
   'level':1,
   'lineId':'9b6a5624-4add-4fce-9de3',
   'loss':0,
   'startTime':1522842642200
}
```

How can it be splited in columns? I tried approach with lambda this but it gives me error `'list index out of range'` and also I don't know how to deal with the second nest:

```
df['details'] = df.loc[:, 'type'].apply(lambda x: x[0]['details'])
```

How can this task be solved?

Comment: try doing `df['details'] = df.loc[:, 'type'].apply(lambda x: x['details'])`

Comment: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: right.. my dataframe must look different to yours then. It will be helpful if you edit your question to include a snapshot of what your dataframe looks like using `df.head()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The options of json_normalize () helped me with that situation:

```
df_df = json_normalize(df['values'], record_path=['type'], meta=['Speed','endTime', 'level','lineId', 'loss', 'startTime'])
```

Answer (score -1):

If i understood your problem correctly, you are working with a multiindex as columns of your dataframe. Though I can't understand what is it you are trying to do with it.

If you want to access the sub-column "details" try something like:

```
df['type']['details']
```

I can't guarantee it will work since I couldn't recreate the dataframe with the data you provided

Maybe this will help

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html